# Bar Chart bars not aligning with x axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've created a bar chart with dates on the x axis, but I cannot get them to line up with the markers. I've tried changing the sorting, the bar width and cannot get them to line up. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: Does each column represent one value on the x-axis? Also, what does the data coming from the dataset look like? And finally, the image is cropped so I can;t see if the markers are dates or datetime values.

Comment: Each column represents a sum of a value for a date, the x axis is the date corresponding to the bar but I think since it's dates SSRS is trying to place the bars chronologically as I have them sorted by largest to smallest sum value as opposed to by date.

Comment: Might be worth posting a sample of your data and your report design. If you could create a stand-alone copy of the rdl with the data generated in the dataset then I'll take a look over the weekend if I get time.